# Validator id is not registered

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

i am getting this warning in eclipse:

```
Validator id is not registered
```

on the line:

```
<f:validator validatorId="confirmPasswordValidator" />
```

i am using JSF 2, and tomcat 6

and my el-impl library is org.glassfish.web

any ideas why ?
and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ignore and run it. Eclipse is relying on it being present as `<validator>` declaration in `faces-config.xml` the JSF 1.x way. It does by default not recognize `@FacesValidator` and likes yet and therefore don't see it already being registered by new JSF 2.x annotations. The upcoming newer Eclipse versions will.

You could consider to turn off JSF validation in Eclipse preferences, it will only lead to more confusion and annoyances. The upcoming [JBoss Tools plugin](http://www.jboss.org/tools) 3.3 (currently still in beta) will support JSF annotations like `@FacesValidator`, `@ManagedBean`, etc.

Note that this is in no way related to EL. You aren't using `#{}` anywhere.